# Download only compiled Bootstrap with a package manager (Bower, npm, Composer)?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, npm, composer-php, bower, package-managers

Is there a way to just get `bootstrap/css`, `bootstrap/js` and `bootstrap/fonts`? Wouldn't mind jQuesry included, though. It does really matter what package manager, as long as I can install it wherever I like and it runs on Mac.

Answer (score 3):

Using `composer` you can define a package repository and utilize the `svn` support of github to get a slice of the tree.

```
{
    "name": "slbmeh/bootstrap-deps",
    "description": "An example to get only specific bootstrap files",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "slbmeh/bootstrap-css",
                "version": "3.2.0",
                "source": {
                    "type": "svn",
                    "url": "https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap",
                    "reference": "tags/v3.2.0/dist/css"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "slbmeh/bootstrap-fonts",
                "version": "3.2.0",
                "source": {
                    "type": "svn",
                    "url": "https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap",
                    "reference": "tags/v3.2.0/dist/fonts"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "slbmeh/bootstrap-js",
                "version": "3.2.0",
                "source": {
                    "type": "svn",
                    "url": "https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap",
                    "reference": "tags/v3.2.0/dist/js"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "slbmeh/bootstrap-all",
                "version": "3.2.0",
                "source": {
                    "type": "svn",
                    "url": "https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap",
                    "reference": "tags/v3.2.0/dist"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "slbmeh/bootstrap-all": "*",
        "slbmeh/bootstrap-css": "*",
        "slbmeh/bootstrap-fonts": "*",
        "slbmeh/bootstrap-js": "*"
    }
}
```

The above composer.json gives you a number of different options to install the packages into your vendor directory.